# How could I dispatch the request by instances' type dynamically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

How could I dispatch the request by instances' type  dynamically

I have a ELB contains an `auto scaling group` and an  indenpendent ec2 machine

However the indenpendent ec2 machine is `t2.large`

and the instances in the `auto scaling group` are `t2.micro`

How could I dispatch the users requests in reasonable way.

From my point, If there are 100 request, I think 90% will go to the `t2.large` and the other 10% go to the `t2.micro` (suppose there is only one instance in the scaling group).

But if there are 2 instances in the scaling group, I think the `scaling group` should take about 15~20% requests.

How could I set the kind of policy with `ELB` and `route 53` thanks so much

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkWn2.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmFIK.png]

Comment: Why don't you just keep all machines in the ELB the same type, and avoid this problem altogether?

Comment: afaik ELB has only two working modes. dispatch requests evenly between availability zones or *try* to dispatch requests evenly betwen machines